# Given sequence $x_n$ in $ [a,b]$ and limit of $x_n$ is $z$. Prove $z$ is in $[a,b]$.

Tags: real-analysis

Given sequence $x_n$ in $ [a,b]$ and limit of $x_n$ is $z$. Prove $z$ is in $[a,b]$.

$a\leq x_n\leq b$ is given and I want to show $a\leq z\leq b$. Since limit of $x_n$ is $z$, $|x_n-z|<\epsilon$  and $|z-\epsilon|<x_n<z+\epsilon$  and this is where I am stuck.

Comment: $[a,b]$ is a closed set, hence all limit points are in the set itself.

Answer (score 2):

Proof by contradiction maybe helpful.

Suppose $z>b$ then by limit definition there exist a first $N$ that $|x_N-z|<z-b$ which means $x_N>b$ contradiction.

Comment: Could you explain how you got |x N −z| < z−b?

Comment: Because $z$ and $b$ are known constants and since $z-b>0$ you can let $\epsilon=z-b$ and apply the definition of limit.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

You can prove a much more general result:

> If $C$ is a closed set and $(x_n)\subset C$ a convergent sequence, then it converge in $C$.

Indeed, let $\ell$ it's limit and suppose $\ell\notin C$, then $\ell\in C^c$ which is open.

I let you continue.